# How to get all parent category using category Id?

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I want all parent category name using category Id

- Main Category

  - Sub Category 1

    - Sub Category 3
    - Sub Category 4
  - Sub Category 2

    - Sub Category 5
    - Sub Category 6

Now I have id of this category **Sub Category 6** Now i want all parent category name means i want this two name **Sub Category 2,Main Category** in frontend How to get all parent category name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);

$catnames = array();
foreach ($category->getParentCategories() as $parent) {
    $catnames[] = $parent->getName();
}
```

Comment: You should go for the solution @Marius proposed, loading entire objects is extremely heavy and adds seconds to load times

Answer (score 7):

Simplest way without loads in loops:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId());
$names = array();
foreach ($category->getParentCategories() as $parent) {
    $names[] = $parent->getName();
}
//do what you need with `$names` array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    // get current path
    $path = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getPath();

    // explode path
    $ids = explode('/', $path);

    foreach($ids as $id) {

        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($id);
        $catName = $cat->getName();

        echo $catName;

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the function `getParentCategories()` then it called the function

load() which is taken more load time.
See:

```
$pathIds = array_reverse(explode(',', $category->getPathInStore()));
        $categories = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
            ->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $pathIds))
            ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
            ->load()
            ->getItems();
```

Then it will better to call  `Custom Category collection` and doesnot use `collection load function` .

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);
 $catnames=array();
$pathIds = array_reverse(explode(',', $category->getPathInStore()));
$Categories = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
            ->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $pathIds))
            ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);


foreach ($Categories as $Eachparent) {
    $catnames[] = $Eachparent>getName();
}
```